# editing json string in php

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to edit a data query using php by passing it through javascript,

my ajax request looks like

```
var totalSearchResult=10;
$.ajax({
    url:"php/queryManipulation.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { totalQuery : totalSearchResult,  query : '{"data":{"match_all":{}}}'},

    success: function(finalList)
    {
        alert(finalList);
    }
});
```

my php code looks like

```
<?php
$from=$_POST["totalQuery"];
$qry=json_decode($_POST["query"]);
$qry->from=$from;   }?>
```

I am trying to get it in the form,

```
{"data": {"match_all": {}} , "from": 10}
```

I get the error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: You forgot to `json_encode` it back?

Comment: And why I'd see an extra `}` at the end of your PHP script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Changed json_decode return value from array to object**

You need to encode the json again just after finishing the edits.
So what you can do is something like:

```
<?php
    $from            = $_POST["totalQuery"];
    $qry             = json_decode($_POST["query"]);
    $qry->data->from = $from;
    //you will get the new json string 
    //as the finalList variable in your post callback
    echo json_encode($qry); 
?>
```

Comment: I get it in the form {"data":{"match_all":[]},"from":"10"}... It should be like{"data":{"match_all":{}},"from":"10"}

Comment: I've changed the answer. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_decode($string, true) - so it will be an array.
Details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can decode to an array (not sure about objects) and re-encode:

```
$qry = json_decode($_POST['query'], TRUE);
$qry['from'] = 10;
$new_qry = json_encode($qry);
```